# scrapy crawl: error: no such option : -o

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run the command `scrapy crawl openings -o items.json -t json` as mentioned in the tutorial, I get:

```
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider|url> ...

crawl: error: no such option: -o
```

I am simply following the scrapy tutorial, when I run the command without the output option it works fine.

```
scrapy crawl openings
```

works fine and I see the crawl output, however it does not work if I want to export the crawl to a JSON.

Searched the web extensively there is no help or mention of this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That option is only for the latest version of Scrapy, which can be found on GitHub.

If you are using version 0.12 (latest stable as can be seen on scrapy.org), you should use:
scrapy crawl openings --set FEED_URI=items.json --set FEED_FORMAT=json

See also: http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/0.12/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data

Comment: Perfect. Love StackOverflow for this.

Comment: Note that 0.14 is the latest version at time of writing this comment, which does support -o items.json -t json